# Crime instrument, is there a term or a common phrase?

Tags: terminology, legalese

As per the title. The problem is that I need to find articles relating to a specific artifact (Machine Learning algorithms) that can be used for crime. If that artifact was a gun, the search "gun crime" would yield good results. However, a search for "Machine Learning crime" mostly returns articles concerning Machine Learning used to detect crime.

Is there a technical term or phrase that I can use that refers to the instrument used in a crime? Thanks!

Comment: “Instrument of crime” is a legal term

Comment: *Weapon*, surely?

Comment: Thanks Clare, you are right, I don't know why I didn't think it was.

Comment: Possibly "paraphernalia". It [means](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/paraphernalia) “*Miscellaneous articles, especially the equipment needed for a particular activity.*” and is a term that is often associated with the instruments of illicit drug use.

Comment: Specifying how a *machine learning algorithm* is an *artefact* would get you half-way.
If *gun crime* would yield good results then find a form of *machine learning* that’s equivalent to *gun*. If *gun*’s too strict, try *weapon*.